# Trouble making linked copies of a document between repositories

Tags: 2010, document-library

I have two document repositories (on seperate site collections) and am trying to link them with one as the source and the other as a copy that can be updated from the source.  This is all following the instructions found [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/copy-a-file-to-another-library-or-send-to-location-HA101782473.aspx) amoung other places.

When I use the 'Send To' command, I get a blank dialog box (server address removed)

[image: Blank Error Dialog]

I have been very unsuccessful in finding much of anything with web searches for this, other than a warning the URL to the document can not exceed 256 characters.  I am getting this error when using the default 'Shared Documents' libraries on both sites -- so I would hope that doesn't cause the error.

I have checked and this dialog box does not trigger any writes to the log files.

Tracing it with the browser shows the dialog is displayed when the copy service is called, but I'm not seeing any network traffic.

I have seen no mention of any, but are there features that need activated to make this work?

Anyone have an idea what is going on with it?

Thanks